# Фильтрация объекта по значениям из массива

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Есть объект, который надо отфильтровать по значениям из массива; свойства из массива гарантированно есть в объекте. Реализовал это таким образом:

```js
const teams = {
    'dynamo': {
      points: 10,
      goals: 10
    },
    'shakhtar': {
      points: 12,
      goals: 10
    },
    'metalist': {
      points: 7,
      goals: 7
    }
  },
  list = ['metalist', 'shakhtar'];

let filteredObj = objectFilter(teams, list);
console.log(filteredObj);

function objectFilter(obj, filterBy) {
  let filtered = {};
  
  for(let key in obj) { // запускаем циклический обход объекта
    filterBy.forEach(function(filterItem) { // сравниваем ключ со всеми элементами массива
      if (key == filterItem) filtered[key] = obj[key];  // и если совпадение есть, записываем пару ключ-значение в новый объект
    });
  }
  
  return filtered;
}
```

Но есть подозрение, что это не самый оптимальный путь. Приведу пример: пар ключ-значение может быть 10000, элементов в массиве всего 5. Для каждого ключа запустится цикл, даже если все 5 элементов уже выбрались за первые, скажем 100 переборов.

Просьба подсказать более лаконичный (если он есть) или более производительный способ для подобных действий.

Comment: `value in array`?

Comment: свойства из `list` гарантированно присутствуют в объекте _teams_?

Comment: @Grundy гарантированно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В Вашем коде плохо то, что происходит обход всего объекта (хотя фильтруем по ключам из массива), плюс - на каждом значении ключа прибавляется ещё и обход массива с ключами.
Стоит один раз обойти ключи:

```js
const teams = {
    'dynamo': {
      points: 10,
      goals: 10
    },
    'shakhtar': {
      points: 12,
      goals: 10
    },
    'metalist': {
      points: 7,
      goals: 7
    }
  },
  list = ['metalist', 'shakhtar'],
  /**
   * Проходимся Array#reduce по ключам
   * Если очередной ключ есть в объекте, добавляем его к аккумулятору по ключу
   *
   * @param Object db   Объект, из которого нужно выбрать значения по ключам
   * @param Array  keys Ключи для выборки
   *
   * @return Object Объект, содержащий только указанные ключи
   */
  filter = (db, keys) => keys.reduce((a, key) => (a[key] = db[key], a), {});

console.info(filter(teams, list));
```

Подробнее:
В [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) инициализируем аккумулятор пустым объектом.
Ему (т. е. `previousValue`) устанавливаем новое свойство из фильтруемого объекта и возвращаем этот же (`previousValue`) объект (через [оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F), оборачивание в скобки необходимо для работы этого оператора), чтобы продолжить аккумулировать на нём всё новые свойства, а затем вернуть.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58390/discussion-on-answer-by-other------).

Answer (score 2):

Обойдемся одним циклом по названиям в `filterBy`, а проверять будем наличие свойств в `obj`, используя поиск свойства по имени javascript-ового движка:

```
function objectFilter(obj, filterBy) {
  var filtered = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < filterBy.length; i++) {
    var item = obj[filterBy[i]];
    if (item)
      filtered[filterBy[i]] = item;
  }

  return filtered;
}
```

Comment: опять без объяснений?

Comment: @Grundy Вы, наверное, уже поняли, что я считаю, что хороший код должен объяснять себя сам :)

Comment: должен :-) но это не то место для само объяснений. Плюс неизвестно, _почему_ этот код лучше чем код в вопросе. Вообще говоря, в вопросе стоит метка _инспекций-кода_ поэтому, просто кусок кода без ничего - это плохой ответ.

Comment: как автор вопроса написал в комментариях - свойства из массива гарантированно есть в объекте, следовательно нет нужды в проверке `item`

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов если необходимо всё таки проверять key:

```js
const teams = {
    'dynamo': {
      points: 10,
      goals: 10
    },
    'shakhtar': {
      points: 12,
      goals: 10
    },
    'metalist': {
      points: 7,
      goals: 7
    }
  },
  list = ['metalist', 'shakhtar1'];


function objectFilter(obj, filterBy) {
    filter = {};
    list.map(function (item) {
        return teams[item] ? filter[item] = teams[item] : false;
    });

   return filter;
}

var filteredObj = objectFilter(teams, list);
console.log(filteredObj);
```

Используем [Array.map](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration), а в тернарнике проверяем наличие поля

Comment: В вопросе и двух ответах написано что поля гарантировано есть. И почему `Array#map`?

Comment: в чем смысл использования `map`?

Comment: не могу найти, но где-то было сравнение с forEach и map оказывался быстрее

Comment: [Вряд ли.](https://jsperf.com/native-map-versus-array-looping) Да и экономия на спичках в скорости, а семантически - гораздо хуже.

Comment: @Other ага, forEach, вообще  быстрее всех отработал

Comment: значит я ошибся

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, результат зависит от браузера: разные браузеры могут показывать разный результат, в некоторых map оптимизирован, в некоторых все вместе, в некоторых ничего. Например: EDGE выдает результативность map почти на уровне `for`, в то время как в Chrome, map оказался намного медленнее чем forEach