# Фильтрация объекта в JS

Tags: javascript, объекты, filter

как сделать фильтрация данного объекта, к примеру, по возрасту?

```js
const teams = {
    '0': {
      Name: 'Vasa',
      Age: 25
    },
    '1': {
      Name: 'Alex',
      Age: 20
    }
  }
  
console.log(teams);
```

Находил похожие тему, как к примеру [вот эта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644787/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0), но слишком сложно.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так. Не самый универсальный пример, но все же

```js
let result = {}
let teams = {
    '0': {
      Name: 'Vasa',
      Age: 25
    },
    '1': {
      Name: 'Alex',
      Age: 20
    }
  }
  
for (i in teams) {
  let team = teams[i]
  // Ниже условие фильтрации
  if (team.Age === 20) {
    result[i] = team
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Будет лучше, если переменная `teams` будет массивом, тогда можно будет писать более гибкий и лаконичный код, например:

```js
     let teams = [{
          Name: 'Vasa',
          Age: 25
        },{
          Name: 'Alex',
          Age: 20
        }]
      
    let result = teams.filter(team => team.Age === 20)
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. С:

Comment: Таким образом Вы наполняете `result` ***ссылками*** на поля `teams`. А значит, при изменении `teams`, изменится и `result` (что может привести к ошибке). Это стоит указать в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const teams = {
    '0': { Name: 'Vasa', Age: 25 },
    '1': { Name: 'Alex', Age: 20 } 
}; 

let filtered = filterBySubField(teams, 'Age', 20);
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered, null, 2));

// возвращает копию объекта obj, содержащую только те поля-объекты, у которых поле subField === value
function filterBySubField(obj, subField, value) {
  let result = {}; 
  for (let k in Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (obj[k][subField] === value) 
      result[k] = Object.assign({}, obj[k]); 
  }
  return result; 
}
```